# How do I show that in an incomplete market general equilibrium, βR<1?

Tags: macroeconomics

Consider the stochastic incomplete market environment, assume endowments are iid and agents face a borrowing constraint where assets have to ge greater than $-\Phi$. Assume that $u$ is strictly increasing and concave.

The recursive problem of a household that has access to a risk-free bond that pays $R=1+r$ every period is
\begin{align}
v(a,s)=&\max_{c,a'}\left\{u(c)+\beta\sum_{s'}\pi(s')v(a',s')\right\}\\
s.t.\;\;& c+a'=(1+r)a+y_s\\
&a'\geq -\Phi
\end{align}

How do I use the Dobb's convergence theorem to show that, using FOCs and envelope conditions, in general equilibrim, $\beta R<1$?